# Existence and uniqueness for second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Given a second-order ODE of the form $$x''(t) = f(t,x(t),x'(t))$$
with initial conditions $x(t_0) = x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x'(t_0) = y_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$

What theorem can be used to prove the existence and uniqueness of solutions to this general equation?

I only know Picard-Lindelöf and the resources I find online are almost all computational. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You convert the problem into the first order system $x'=y,y'=f(t,x,y)$, and then apply a theorem such as Picard-Lindelöf for first order systems.